# Using Sandcastle Help File Builder with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, sandcastle

How can I make Sandcastle Help File Builder create help files from projects being built using MSBuild?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an MSBuild Target that builds my documentation in my build-script.

This target uses Sandcastle Helpfile Builder.

It is done like this:

```
<Target name="builddoc" DependsOnTargets="buildall">

   <ItemGroup>
      <Assemblies Include="-assembly=$(outputdir)\myassembly.dll" />
      <Assemblies Include="-assembly=$(outputdir)\anotherassembly.dll" />
   </ItemGroup>

   <Exec Command="$(double_quote)$(SandcastleHFBCmd)$(double_quote) sandcastleproj.shfb$(double_quote) @(assemblies, ' ') outputpath=$(outdir)
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [docproject](http://www.codeplex.com/DocProject)
that's what we use to build help files from within our TFS build scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the commands used by Sandcastle Help File Builder and copy them to you build process.